# plugin to take annotations on a pdf in a HTML5 mobile app

Tags: html, pdf, jquery-mobile

Using jQueryMobile and html5 I've build a mobile application in which I need to retrieve a pdf file from an external url, saving inside the app and give the possibility to take annotations on the this file.

So I'm wondering if there is a plugin that I can use to take annotations on pdf.

Thank you very much in advance.
Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: What did you end up choosing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used any of these but here are a couple that might help:

- http://snipplr.com/view/9250/
- http://www.zurb.com/playground/javascript-annotation-plugin
- http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/annotations.htm
- http://code.google.com/p/xsd-forms/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll check them out. If you believe you can also vote for my question.

Comment: @bobighorus I did vote for your question as I thought is was a good question!